# How to determine if mac SDK is *less* than

Tags: c, macos

I have an application that target a minimum platform of 10.5, and it compiles fine with SDK 10.6 or 10.7.

However, when compiling with an old version of xcode with 10.5 SDK, compilation fails and requires some extra #import (why it does I'm not sure, but it does). When I import the OpenGL header, I get an error about some types being unresolved. Adding `#import <CarbonCore/Endian.h>` fixes the problem (that's where the missing symbols are located).

I do not want to perform the #import unless absolutely necessary, and in particular not do it when compiling with 10.6 or 10.7.

I know how to check if I'm using a SDK that is superior to a given version, like so:

```
#if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5 > MACS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
// Mac > 10.5 code here
#endif
```

Problem is testing the reverse condition has proven to be non-trivial as all the later version of the SDK have all the defines found in earlier versions.

I'd like to find the equivalent of:

```
#if COMPILING_WITH_10_5_OR_EARLIER
blah
#endif
```

Surely, there must be an easy way I've overlooked

Comment: Good question! +1 from me. This is something I will stumble over in future, I know, so it's valuable to have someone ask the question and perhaps get answers.

Comment: `#else` seems like it ought to do it?

Comment: I should add that I'm compiling with: g++ -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5

Comment: "#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED <= __MAC_10_5" is what you are looking for (max-allowd is the SDK version set for the project)

Answer (score 7):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > 1050  // note use of 1050 instead of __MAC_10_5
#   include <security/pam_appl.h>
#else
#   include <pam/pam_appl.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
#ifndef MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6
#include <CarbonCore/Endian.h>
#endif
```

which will include `<CarbonCore/Endian.h>` if (and only if) the `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6` macro is not defined.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple.. I add tried that solution earlier. I added: #ifndef MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6 #error "Need 10.6SDK" #else #error "Not needing 10.6 SDK" #endif. The error I get is "Not needing 10.6 SDK". So even on 10.5 SDK, on my 10.6 box running xcode 3.2, MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6 is defined

Comment: @jyavenard: O.K., I think I understand . . . hmm. What is `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` set to?

Comment: I'm not sure how I could see its value. I normally compile in the command line, but for ease of testing, I created an XCode project. MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED is a macro defined in /usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h. I think for ease safe, I'm just going to add a custom compilation flag set by a script that checks what the current SDK is. and update CFLAGS/CXXFLAGs with -DUSING_10_5_SDK. I thought there had to be a more official way to do so, one that wouldn't require any external test

Comment: Since it's a macro that expands to an integer literal, you can see its value by writing a program with `#include <stdio.h>` and `int main() { printf("%d\n", MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED); return 0; }`. That said -- my understanding (based on the docs I've found online) is that it's intended to be user-settable, just like `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED`, with `<AvailabilityMacros.h>` only setting it to a default value if it hasn't already been set. Have I misunderstood something?